# Implementation of raymarching surfaces in GLSL

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, glsl

I've been reading up on a lot of various articles regarding to ray-marching in GLSL shaders (such as this one article: http://www.iquilezles.org/www/articles/rmshadows/rmshadows.htm) and it raised some questions that I wanted to ask.

In my application, I am rendering a scene with a couple of meshes and I wanted to experiment with shadows. While I seem to somewhat understand the concept of how raymarching works, I don't quite understand how to properly implement this in GLSL. I know how to compute the intersection of a ray and a plane but how would this be handled through GLSL shaders?

According to this thread here: (https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/67719/how-do-raymarch-shaders-work) it mentions that you're measuring the distance between the start of the ray and the 'surface'. Is the surface he's referring to the mesh? Do I need to send an array of planes/points that makes up the mesh to the shader in order to compute the ray intersection test? Do I need to use the depth buffer to determine the distance of the surface?

Comment: Regarding the last point, yes shadow maps are tremendously helpful for this purpose. Have a look at this very recent [presentation from GDC '14](https://developer.nvidia.com/sites/default/files/akamai/gameworks/events/gdc14/GDC_14_From%20Terrain%20to%20Godrays%20-%20Better%20Use%20of%20DirectX11CantlayTatarinov.pdf) at around slides 71-81. Although its focus is primarily on a particular optimization of a ray-marching algorithm using tessellation, the diagrams may help you conceptually.

Comment: So I suppose the shadowmap is the only way to pull off this effect. Suppose in my shader I take the framebuffer image from the camera's POV and the depthbuffer from the light source's POV and for each pixel, trace from the start of the light to the pixel (after being converted to 3D space coordinates) and compare it with the pixel of the framebuffer. Though this is starting to sound a lot like ray tracing instead of ray marching.

Comment: Well, yes.. but that is not a good application of ray marching in the first place. If you just want to find the distance to the first point that completely blocks light, you can do that with the shadow map alone. Ray marching is designed to do integration using a finite amount of sampled data instead of an analytic approach; think of computing the area under a curve using the trapezoid rule and approximations of the area under several sub-intervals. It is useful for computing things like how much light is blocked by a non-uniform volume of smoke, given the density of the smoke at a few points.

Comment: So it seems more ideal for something like SSAO or for smoothing out the shadow map?

Comment: More or less, volumetric lighting and more physically based light sources such as area lights make heavy use of ray marching as well. Consider the diagrams on [this page](http://www.polygonpi.com/?p=318) and pay particular attention to the area light (sun) versus point light (don't really exist in nature).

Answer (score 0):

It's depend of what your shader does vs what your rendering engin does. In pure demo shaders like shadertoy (see its [shadow examples](https://www.shadertoy.com/results?query=shadows) ) the whole scene is encoded in the shader so there is no problem shooting secondary rays or more (beside perfs).

If the scene is not managed by your shader, then you need a bit of cooperation from your engine. At least, to produce a shadowmap in a first pass (many different algorithms exists). 
Note that with SVO representation, the scene is first converted into sparse voxels, which can then be marched by the shader for secondary rays. Could be even for primary ray, but you do can use regular Z-buffer here, and voxel cone-tracing (for instance) for all kinds of secondary rays ( see *Interactive Indirect Illumination Using Voxel Cone Tracing * here: http://gigavoxels.imag.fr/publications.html  (ok, you might find it overkill in your simple application). For soft shadows and depth of field, see the seminal paper *GigaVoxels : Ray-Guided Streaming for Efficient and Detailed Voxel Rendering* . Note that the tree might even be a regular BSP of triangles, instead of on octree of voxels. But then you loose many advantage of SVO (perfs, increased for soft shadows).

Answer (score 0):

Raymarching the way iq/RGBA (Inigo Quilezles) explains it, is raymarching of signed distance functions ("SDF"s).  This is a completely mathematical approach for describing a scene.

We only render a screen quad, the whole world to display is made up of fragment shader code that either manipulates space, or calculates the signed distance to some mathematically defined entity, or even combines the distances of different objects.

Simple example for such might be:

```
float fTorus(vec3 p, float smallRadius, float largeRadius)
{
    return length(vec2(length(p.xz) - largeRadius, p.y)) - smallRadius;
}
vec2 pR( inout vec2 p, in float radians )
{   
    p = cos( radians ) * p + sin( radians ) * vec2( p.y, -p.x ) );
    return p;
}
vec2 world( in vec3 p )
{
    pR( p.xz, radians( -45 ) );   // manipulate Space - rotate around Y
    p -= vec3( 0.0, 0.0, 10.0 ); // manipulate Space - move (after rot)
    return vec2( fTorus( p ), float( 1 ) );
    // finally return distance to torus in x and the material number in y
}
```

This world code describes a torus at a position in the world resulting from the rotation and the translation given to "p" in the "world" function.  Note that we modify Space inversely, like in camera space, so to move to a point in space, we have to subtract its vector from p.

Anyhow, that's where the geometry comes from in the purely analytical approach iq presents.  Maybe a good further read: http://mercury.sexy/hg_sdf/